# ways to passing byte array to fileinputstream in java

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

I have a query that is in the below code i have a file name as shown below

```
String filename = "C:\\abcd\\Ttre.xls";
```

which later on i am passing to `FileInputStream` object as shown below

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileStream);
```

the happy case above was that filename was hardcoded which was pass to the `FileInputStream` object  but lets say if some one is giving me file in form of byte array then how to deal with that case for example
 as shown below

```
public void abcd( byte[] excelByteStream) {
    //how to pass the the byte array file to the FileInputStream object 
}
```

so in that case how we would pass the bytestream file to the `FileInputStream` object please advise

Comment: What is HSSFWorkbook? Can in handle an `InputStream` in its constructor or does it specifically need a `FileInputStream`?

Comment: @SkinnyJ it can also , i have shown the explicit one can you show please how we can pass the input stream in it's constructor also

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  `FileInputStream` is a type of `InputStream` that expects a file as input.

To use a byte array, you would use `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`, which is also another type of `InputStream`.

Just make sure that whatever is expecting an input stream is defined to accept the more generic `InputStream`. (e.g.: `public HSSFWorkbook(InputStream inputStream) { // HSSFWorkbook constructor definition`)

Documentation: [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

**EDIT: A more complete example**

If your `HSSFWorkbook` class has the constructor currently defined as:

```
public HSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream inputStream) {
    // ...
}
```

... you would want to change it to accept the more generic `InputStream` class, which would now allow you to pass it either a `FileInputStream` or a `ByteArrayInputStream` instance depending on where you call it from.  Like this:

```
public HSSFWorkbook(InputStream inputStream) {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can instantiate your `HSSFWorkbook` using either option:

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileStream); // still works
```

... or ...

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(excelByteStream);
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(byteArrayInputStream ); // now also works.
```

Comment: Thanks can you also please correct my above posted code that will help to grasp more Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream(byte[])) instead of FileInputStream:

```
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelByteStream);
```